# Flutter how to protect from null values when getting attribute values of snapshot

Tags: flutter, dart, null, ternary-operator, snapshot

I have data coming back from firestore which is either coming back null or temporarily coming back null.

I do a check to make sure the snapshot has data like this:

```
parentSnapshot.data != null && parentSnapshot.hasData
```

I also tried to protect for the attribute being null using a ternary like this:

```
var isParent = parentSnapshot.data['isParent'] ?? false;
```

But for some reason I still keep getting:

```
The method '[]' was called on null
Reciever: null
Tried calling: []("isParent")
```

It needs to be null safe so if that attribute is not found then the variable always returns false so I control what is displayed.

Here is the full code:

```
return StreamBuilder<Object>(
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection(parent).document(
            widget.menuItemsList[index]['name']).snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot parentSnapshot) {

          if (parentSnapshot.data != null && parentSnapshot.hasData) {
            var isParent = parentSnapshot.data['isParent'] ?? false;

            if (isParent){
              return GridButtons(widget.menuItemsList[index]['name'], animation, index, parent, collection, parentSnapshot, widget.menuItemsList, widget.listKey);
            } else {
              return SizedBox(width: 0, height: 0,);
            }

          } else {
            return SizedBox(width: 0, height: 0,);
          }
        }
    );
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I think below code will help you

we have to check length also

if condition only accepts Boolean values in dart language

```
if (parentSnapshot.hasData && parentSnapshot.data != null && parentSnapshot.data.length > 0 ) {
            var isParent = parentSnapshot.data['isParent'] != null ? true : false;

            if (isParent){
              return GridButtons(widget.menuItemsList[index]['name'], animation, index, parent, collection, parentSnapshot, widget.menuItemsList, widget.listKey);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It turns out I was calling and invalid collection but it was returning a result without error. That's why the fields were missing